# Upload image to Firebase storage Java Desktop

Tags: java, firebase, desktop-application, firebase-storage

I'm doing a desktop application along with firebase, I can register, change and delete database records using the Firebase4j example that they made available themselves, but I have no idea how to save an image in Storage through JFileChooser.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setDialogTitle("Selecione a imagem!");
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();

            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
            baos.flush();
            Base64 base = new Base64(false);
            String encodedImage = base.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
            baos.close();
            encodedImage = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(encodedImage, "ISO-8859-1");
```

I just found Java for Android, I did not find any examples for the desktop.

Comment: In Android all you need is the path,  try to upload that. A tricky thing is, you have to provide file name whith ectensiom while uploading to storage; yourstorage/folder/file.jpg

Comment: @cutiko Like i said, i'm not using java for android, is a desktop application.